# How to position divs above the intersection of 2 other divs?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

How to position divs above the intersection of 2 other divs ?
I did try with relative and absolute positioning. But wasn't able to achieve a good result.

[image]

I have tried with relative and absolute positions in div1, div3 and I kept div3 inside div1 and increased its height. But after I placed the contents in div2 and tried to do a similar structure, the alinment got completly distorted.
Can anyone please help me with some better approach? Can it be acheived by css grids ?

Comment: You don't need CSS grids to achieve this. However, it is unclear from your question how your markup is structured: can you share a [minimal, concrete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bu6Lyzp2/8/

Comment: Hi @Terry ! thanks for the response! Here is a decription: div1 and div3 are inside the main container of the page. div1 constitue the top 30% of the page and div3- the rest 70%. And the div 2 is placed just above the position in which div1 and di3 meet. I hope this make it clear somewhat!

Comment: That is basically what your screenshot illustrates, but does not give any **structure** indications. How are the divs nested? Are div1 and div3 siblings? Are div2 nested in either, or is it also a sibling?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.. it will help you....

```css
.div1 {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: relative;
}
.div-2-half {
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 49%;
    float: left;
}
.div2 {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    background: transparent;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 41px;
}
.div3 {
  background-color: #fff;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.div4 {
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 23px;
}
.div-container {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
<p>div 1</p>

</div>
<div class="div-container">
  <div class="div2">
    <div class="div-2-half">
      <p>div 2</p>
      <div class="div4">div4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="div-2-half"><p>div 2</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class="div3"><p style="text-align:center; padding-top: 50px;">div 3</p></div>
</div>
```